# Vida/Vigencia de un array en un método JAVA

Tags: java, array

Os planteo una duda que me ha surgido examinando un código que no es mío, pero con el que tengo que trabajar, igual es una tontería pero me tiene un poco crujido, he buscado alguna pregunta parecida a esta, pero no he encontrado. Supongamos este código muy resumido:

```
 0 public static float metodoA(){

    1 float [] array0 = new float[tamaño];
    2 //Inicializo array0 con valores, los que sean
    3 int[] array1 = new int[tamaño];
    4 array1 = metodoX(array0);

   }

 5 private static int[] metodoX (float[] array0){

    6 int[] array3 = new int[tamaño];
    7  //hago operaciones entre array0 y array3 las que sean (de copiar de un lado a otro)
    8  return array3; //Devuelvo este array
```

Mi duda es, yo me he creado un array que es mi array1 en la línea 3, se supone que al hacer new está en memoria creado con el tamaño que sea (tamaño).
En el metodo x yo me creo un array3, y ocupa espacio en memoria porque hago un new. Bien, despues de terminar el método X devuelve ese array3 y lo referencia array1. Vale la duda que tengo es, array3 tras terminar el método en el que ha sido creado, ¿"desaparece"? Es decir, es el array1 el que "recoge" el valor de array3 no? Pero con ese array1=metodoX(array0) lo que haces es referenciar array1 a array3, problema, yo tengo creado array1, si lo referencio a array3, pierdo la referencia de array1, luego no tendría sentido hacer el new de array1 no? Simplemente declararlo sin hacer un new, y referenciarlo a lo que devuelva el método.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu sospecha que no tiene sentido de hacer el `new` de array1 es correcta. Lo que podrías hacer para evitar a malgastar recursos (asignar memoria a un arreglo que nunca se usa para luego ser borrado por gc) es lo siguiente:

```
public static float metodoA(){

    float [] array0 = new float[tamaño];
    //Inicializo array0 con valores, los que sean
    int[] array1; // solamente declara el tipo de variable sin asignar
    array1 = metodoX(array0);
}
```

o

```
public static float metodoA(){

    float [] array0 = new float[tamaño];
    //Inicializo array0 con valores, los que sean
    // declarar el tipo de variable y asignar con el retorno del método de una
    int[] array1 = metodoX(array0);
}
```

Tu `array3` esta declarado localmente como variable dentro del método. Así el arreglo (los datos) no desaparecen, porque el método pasa una referencia a ellos como retorno, pero la referencia `array3` no es visible fuera del método y así para el resto del código deja existir en el momento de la salida del método.

Comment: Vale perfecto, muchísimas gracias por tu tiempo y tu respuesta. Como no llevo mucho tiempo, a veces cosas como estas me cuestan, y viene bien la ayuda :)